# id cannot be used in graphQL where clause?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo

```
{
  members {
    id
    lastName
  }
}
```

When I tried to get the data from members table, I can get the following responses.

```
{   "data": {
    "members": [
      {
        "id": "TWVtYmVyOjE=",
        "lastName": "temp"
      },
      {
        "id": "TWVtYmVyOjI=",
        "lastName": "temp2"
      }
    ]   } }
```

However, when I tried to update the row with 'id' where clause, the console shows error.

```
mutation {
    updateMembers(
      input: {
        values: {
          email: "testing@test.com"
        },
        where: {
          id: 3
        }
      }
    ) {
      affectedCount
      clientMutationId
    } 
}
```

> "message": "Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'",

Some results from above confused me.

1. Why the id returned is not a numeric value? From the db, it is a number.
2. When I updated the record, can I use numeric id value in where clause?

I am using nodejs, [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) and [graphql-sequelize-crud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-sequelize-crud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: check out my possibly not `relay` compatible PR here https://github.com/Glavin001/graphql-sequelize-crud/pull/30

Basically, the internal source code is calling the `fromGlobalId` API from `relay-graphql`, but passed a primitive value in it (e.g. your `3`), causing it to return `undefined`. Hence I just removed the call from the source code and made a pull request.

P.S. This buggy thing which used my 2 hours to solve failed in build, I think this solution may not be consistent enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
mutation {
    updateMembers(
      input: {
        values: {
          email: "testing@test.com"
        },
        where: {
          id: "3"
        }
      }
    ) {
      affectedCount
      clientMutationId
    } 
}
```